# Assigning an array as a react component state property?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, state, setstate

When trying to set a non empty array as a component state property (at initialisation, in the component constructor), like for example:

```
this.state = { results: ['apple','orange'] } //in the component constructor
```

this error is returned in the console:

> In this environment the sources for assign MUST be an object.This
>   error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant

If the array is empty though, that works (but as soon as you try to reasign a non empty array, it would bug)

So this works:

```
this.state = { results: [] }  //in the component constructor
```

until you do

```
this.setState({results: ['apple','orange'] }) //in a component function
```

at which point the previous error would be returned...

I don't understand. Aren't javascript arrays supposed to be of the type object too and thus usable as a state property value?

I tested it with the latest react-native version (0.45.1), on an android device.

The state.results object is only used in a listview like this:

```
   const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 })

  render () {
    return (

    <ListView 
              style={{position: 'absolute', width: 100, backgroundColor: 'white', zIndex: 3}}
              keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
              initialListSize={15}
              enableEmptySections={true}
              dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.results)}
              renderRow={(rowData, sectionId, rowId, highlightRow) =>
                <RowWrapper styles={styles.rowWrapper} >
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    activeOpacity={0.5}
                    onPress={() => {this.onItemPress(this.state.results[rowId])}}
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.rowText}>{rowData}</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </RowWrapper>
              }
            />
   )
  }

    class RowWrapper extends Component {
      constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.defaultTransitionDuration = 500
        this.state = {
          opacity: new Animated.Value(0)
        }
      }
      componentDidMount () {
        Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: this.defaultTransitionDuration
        }).start()
      }
      render () {
        return (
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            <Animated.View style={{...this.props.styles, opacity: this.state.opacity }}>
              {this.props.children}
            </Animated.View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, can you post more code? What you posted should work fine, so I believe the error is because of something else in your code. btw are you using Object.assign anywhere or post where you're using this.state.results. thanks

Comment: @MattAft . I edited my first post with the part of code where I am using this.state.results. I don't use Object.assign anywhere and the listview is the only part of my code where this.state.results are read (else it only appear in the component construcor with this.state = { results: [] }  and in a component function where it is overwriten with this.setState({results : ['apple','orange']}) but it is where the issue occur...)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mutate the state.
instead of doing

```
this.setState({results: ['apple','orange'] })
```

You should be doing

```
var resultsArr = this.state.results.slice();
var newResults = ['apple','orange'];
resultsArr.concat(newResults); or resultsArr.push(newResults);
this.setState({results: resultsArr })
```

Comment: I don't mutate the state directly as I am calling this.setState() which is supposed to merge what's passed in argument with the component state...
I don't see what is the difference between doing:
var newResults = ['apple','orange'];
this.setState({results: newResults })
directly and 
var resultsArr = this.state.results.slice();
var newResults = ['apple','orange'];
resultsArr.concat(newResults); 
this.setState({results: resultsArr })
exept making an unecessary empty temporary array...

Comment: Anyway your code doesn't fix the issue and as I said, the error occur if I directly init a state property with a non empty array too. So this is not related to mutating the state or not...

Comment: Can you try this:
`this.setState({ results: [this.state.results.concat['apple', 'orange'] ] })`

With es6
`this.setState({ results: [...this.state.results, ...['apple', 'orange'] ] })`